# How to read pixel values from image in Rust

Tags: image-processing, rust

I am using the [piston Rust image library](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/image) (version 0.10.3) like so:

```
extern crate image;

use std::f32;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;


use image::GenericImage;
use image::Pixels;
use image::Pixel;

fn init(input_path: &str) {
    let mut img = image::open(&Path::new(input_path)).unwrap();

    let img_width = img.dimensions().0;
    let img_height = img.dimensions().1;

    for p in img.pixels() { println!("pixel: {}", p.2.channel_count()); }
}

fn main() {
    init("file.png");
}
```

This example fails with an error message

```
error: no method named `channel_count` found for type `image::Rgba<u8>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:55
   |
20 |     for p in img.pixels() { println!("pixel: {}", p.2.channel_count()); }
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<std macros>:2:27: 2:58 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:20:29: 20:72 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
   |
   = note: found the following associated functions; to be used as methods, functions must have a `self` parameter
note: candidate #1 is defined in the trait `image::Pixel`
  --> src/main.rs:20:55
   |
20 |     for p in img.pixels() { println!("pixel: {}", p.2.channel_count()); }
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<std macros>:2:27: 2:58 note: in this expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: in this expansion of print! (defined in <std macros>)
src/main.rs:20:29: 20:72 note: in this expansion of println! (defined in <std macros>)
```

Which i understand is true, because the documentation mentions that the method I want to have is part of the [Pixel trait](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/trait.Pixel.html#tymethod.channel_count) - the documentation doesn't really make it clear how to access a single pixel in a buffer loaded from an existing image, it mostly talks about getting pixels from `ImageBuffer`.

How can I iterate over all pixels in an image and get rgb/other values from it?

EDIT: After reading the source code, I worked around this by calling `Pixel::channels(&self)` which takes `&self`, therefore I figured out this must be a method added via the trait to objects that implement Pixel.

So the signature of `channel_count()` has neither parameters nor `&self`. How am I supposed to call this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're trying to call, `channel_count()`, is a static method. It is defined for a type, not for an object of that type. You call it with

```
Rgba::channel_count()
```

or

```
<Rgba<u8> as Pixel>::channel_count()
```

as the first form will likely fail (in this instance) due to lack of type information.

However, I don't think it will give you what you want. It should just return the number `4` as that is the number of channels that `Rgba` has.

To get what you want, the RGB values, take a look at the documentation for the type you have, [`Rgba`](http://www.piston.rs/image/image/struct.Rgba.html).

It has a public member, `data`, which is a 4-element array, and it implements `Index`.

If `pixel` is of type `Rgba<u8>` (corresponding to your `p.2`), you can get the values you seek either by calling `pixel.data` which will give them to you as an array, or by indexing. For example, `pixel[0]` will give you the red value.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. This was quite confusing, I thought `channel_count` would be a method for the `Pixel` instance.